# PyGame Inconsistent Framerate

Tags: pygame

This is the first game I have tried to make on PyGame, and I have followed the PyGame Primer tutorial (https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/) to do so. I'm practically done, but when I run the game, it runs incredibly slowly when I provide no input. when I spam-click an arrow key, the game will run smoothly, but if I don't do anything or hold down a key, it will run at < 10 FPS. How could I change it so that it will run consistently regardless of input? This is my code:

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 25
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Images/Star-Rider.png').convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -20)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 20)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-20, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(20, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > 800:
            self.rect.right = 800
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        elif self.rect.bottom > 600:
            self.rect.bottom = 600

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Images/Hand-Projectile.png').convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(random.randint(820, 900), random.randint(0,600)))
        self.speed = random.randint(5,20)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 1000)

player = Player()


enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_enemy = Enemy()
            enemies.add(new_enemy)
            all_sprites.add(new_enemy)

        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed_keys:
            player.update(pressed_keys)

        enemies.update()

        screen.fill((135,206,250))

            screen.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
            player.kill()

        pygame.display.flip()

        fpsclock.tick(FPS)
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this! Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is uuh, ordered incorrectly. You're doing

- While the game is running

  - For each event

    - Handle the event
    - Render a frame

Your logic should be

- While the game is running

  - For each event

    - Handle the event
  - Render a frame

Indentation matters in python. You probably want to unindent everything from pressed_keys and down.

Comment: and for the rest of the answer.